# Proactive export testcases from MTM

Tags: tfs, mtm

Today faced a challenge, due to some infrastructure issue our TFS and MTM was down and the whole testing team was sitting idle as they can't access their test scripts. Is there a way that we can export/download test scripts from MTM to local machine (as we do for codebase i.e. local machine copy) so as to avoid this type of problem.

I know this will be a common problem but somehow unable to find a answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can export an entire test plan from the web interface and you have the possibility to choose if the test cases with steps are included or not in the export.

Comment: Which version of TFS do you have?

Comment: The export feature is part of TFS2013 with Update 2 (or later). You can find your TFS version (not MTM version) by browsing to http://<your tfs server>:8080/tfs then clicking on the upper right button (the one with a question mark) then on About.

Comment: Thanks ds, My version is TFS 2012. IN that I can write a query and select particular Testtype--> List of all test cases comes which can be exported to excel but only titles and other column not test steps. Also now way I can export complete testsuite.

Comment: Then you can try to use this tool: Export Test Cases from TFS (or MTM) to Excel: https://tfstestcaseexporttoexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You cant export for offline access. You can create static report of all of the test cases and steps in the web access. There is however no easy to get the data back in.

To be honest this is not a common ask as most folks TFS servers do not randomly go offline. As TFS is a production system you should get at least four nines SLA. If you don't then I would recommend that you move your TFS to VSO.

Comment: Thanks for reply, It was not that TFS was down my bad in asking question, it was due to infrastructure problem one of our location is unable to connect that. Tool by @ds19 seems good till I move to TFS 2013.